# General approach to count word occurrence in large number of files

Tags: algorithm

This is sort of an algorithm question. To make it clear, I'm not interested in working code but in how to approach the task generally.

> We have a server with 4 CPU's, and no databases. There are 100,000 HTML documents, stored on disk. Each document is 2MB in size. We need an efficient way to determine the count of the word "CAMERA" (case insensitive) appearing in that collection.

My approach would be to

- parse the HTML document to extract only words
- and then sort the words,
- then use binary search on that collection.

In other words, I would create threads to let them use all 4 CPU's to parse the HTML documents into a single, large word collection text file, then sort it, and then using binary search.

What do you think of this?

Comment: To fine tune your approach more data is needed. For example, are the HTML documents on disk? on RAM? Are you getting them from http request? What is the size of each? Note that 100K docs is not that large scale, the overhead of creating the threads might not worth it if they are relatively small and stored on RAM.

Comment: Amit post updated.  I am not getting them from http request.

Comment: do you need to find just file names which contain this word, or you must get exact locations of every occurrence?

Comment: people who do not know the answer please go away. I really do not understand why there is DOWN VOTE. I did enough homework before updating the post.

Comment: Hi MVP, i need the COUNT of word "Camera"

Comment: @iShare: More follow up questions. Do you have any data on how the files stored on disk? i.e. Are the files sequential? Do you know the architecture of your disk (RAID 0/1/2/3/4/5)? Is it a single disk? For single disk, I doubt multithreading will help, since the bottleneck will be to READ the files, which cannot be done in parallel assuming a single disk. Also, are you looking how many times the word CAMERA appears in the colletion, or how many documents contain that word?

Comment: `grep -rio camera path/to/html/documents | wc -l`

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried grep? That's what I would do.

It will probably take some experimentation to figure out the right way to pass it so much data and make sure ahead of time that the results come out right, because it's going to take a little while.

I would not recommend sorting that much data.

Answer (score 0):

If your documents are located on single local hard drive, you will be constrained by I/O, not CPU.

I would use very simple approach of simply serially loading every file into memory and scanning memory searching for target word and increasing counter.

If you try to use 4 threads in attempt to speed it up (like 25000 files to every thread), it will likely make it slower, because I/O does not like overlapping access patterns from competing processes/threads.

If, however, files are spread accross multiple hard drives, you should start as many threads as you have drives, and each thread should read data from that drive only.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it is not a complete pseudo code answer, but I don't think there is one. To get optimal performance you need to know a LOT on your HW architecture. Here are the notes:

1. There is **no need to sort the data** at all, nor use binary search. Just read the files (read each file sequentially from disk) and while doing so search if the word camera appears in it.
2. The **bottle neck in the program will most likely be IO** (disk reads), since disk access is MUCH slower then CPU calculations. So, to optimize the program - one should focus on optimizing the disk reads.
3. To optimize the disk reads, one should know the architecture of it. For example, **if you have only one disk (and no RAID), there is really no point in multi-threading**, assuming the disk can process a single request at the same time. If it is the case - use a single thread.
4. However, if you have multiple disks - it does not matter how many cores you have, you should **spawn #disks threads** (assuming the files are evenly seperated among the disks). Since it is the bottle-neck, by having multiple threads that concurrently requesting the data from the disks, you make all of them work, and effectively reduce the time consumption significantly.

Comment: I would disagree with single threaded solution in case of one disk. A thread reading the next block while another thread analyzing the previous would be, at least slightly, faster.

Comment: @Shahbaz: I disagree. Reading from blocks is done in BLOCKS (by default in any HW I am aware of). You process/analyze block `x` while the disk reads block `x+1`. If your HW cannot support it (asynchroneous disk request), there could be a point to optimize it to using 2 threads, assuming of course the overhead of passing the data from 1 thread to the other is relatively small.

Comment: scanning string in memory should be at least 10x faster than reading from fastest hard drive - hardly 10%. however, loss from 2 concurrent threads competing for I/O should be much more than 10%

Comment: @mvp: Actually, since the data is probably loaded to cpu-cache as part of the disk read (not sure about this one), I suspect much more then 10x faster memory read comparing to the disk read. In addition, you really can do it in parallel assuming your HW supports asynchroneous disk read (that lets you continue calculations until the disk is done and then sends you a HW interrupt).

Comment: absolutely, we are in violent agreement here :)

Comment: @amit, that is exactly what I was saying. While one thread is busy fetching the next block, the other thread processes it.

Comment: @Shahbaz: Read the comments, it is unlikely to help, the same thread can work on calculations of block `x` (and it will finish it before the HW interrupts you to say it is done with the next block) while the HW (disk, no need for thread to do it) "works on" reading the next block.

Comment: @amit, assuming non-blocking I/O yes.

Answer (score 0):

Something like?

```
htmlDocuments = getPathsOfHtmlDocuments()
threadsafe counter = new Counter(0)
scheduler = scheduler with max 4 threads
for(htmlDocument: htmlDocuments){
  scheduler.schedule(new SearchForCameraJob("Camera",htmlDocument,counter))
}
wait while scheduler.hasUnfinishedJobs
print Found camera +counter+ times


class SearchForCameraJob(searchString, pathToFile, counter){
    document = readFile(pathToFile);
    while(document.findNext(searchString)){
    counter.increment();    
   }
}
```

Comment: note that on single hard drive this will work *slower* compared to not using threads at all

Comment: You are just giving a trivial algorithm without any analysis. The point of the interview question had certainly been understanding what affects performance and discuss those.

Comment: @iShare can you explain why you select this as the best answer?

Comment: @Shahbaz The (original) question was pseudocode, nothing more or less. Also, it's not clear who asked or where the question is asked, so performance or some other assumptions might not be relevant.

Comment: @Adrian: Actually, the original answer was:  `I'm looking for an **efficient** algorithm for searching the word "CAMERA" .... Any suggestions, advice, or algorithms ...` (From the edit history). Efficiency "or other assumptions" are VERY relevant for answering the question. Plus, it was stated it is from an interview, where a discussion is a very important thing to let the interviewer know the dilemas and trade-offs of different approaches

Comment: (*) ^ The original answer -> The original question (5 minutes edit limit timed out)

Comment: @amit Yep, even if it was in an interview the question was "write", so it could mean the candidate had to write something down what is analysed after the interview. There was nothing said of a discussion. 
I think we all know that there simple are to few information for a really good answer.

Comment: Adrian, it was asked in the interview. so i wanted to understand the problem well to answer it. i wanted to know in theoretical way. i do not want any source code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Boyer-Moore algorithm. Is difficult to say what programming language is proper for make such of application, but you can make it in C++ so as to directly optimize your native code. Obviously you need to use multithreading. 
Of the HTML document parsing libraries you can choose Xerces-C++.

Comment: I am looking for algorithm. i mean, can i use binary search or not? if not then why?.... this question is not language dependent.

Comment: I've already suggested algorithm. Usually Binary search is a simple algorithm for a small or medium collection of data. Since you describe your hardware performance have suggested an approach regarding language and that should work.